# Unable to restore Envince as default pdf viewer

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, file-association

I don't know why, but somehow "ImageMagick" gained the status of being my default PDF viewing application (I didn't set it manually, maybe it came with the installation of iscan or plex).

Now, when I try to set Envince - or any other viewer - via [right-click on a PDF] > [Properties] > [Open with...] it happens nothing! ImageMagick remains as associated application.

Is there any way to get rid of that association? I guess ImageMagick is somehow made the systemwide standard on root level.

Comment: @fifaltra thank you, i know. but askubuntu wont allow me to do this before i have waited 2 days...

Comment: ah, ok, sorry. I just comment that to all new users I see, because surprisingly many of them don't seem to know. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem:

Rename or delete

```
~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

That's it :-)

If you've set other than default apps for certain filetypes open System Settings > Information > Default Associations and (re)set your favourites there...

Comment: Removing the whole file is a bad idea. @viky's answer is better.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to delete the file and lose all the associations. You could just remove the lines that associate PDF to imagemagick. I just removed the following lines from `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, and it worked!

```
image/pdf=display-im6.desktop
image/pdf=display-im6.q16.desktop;display-im6.desktop;
```

Comment: Or you can set your preferred application instead of removing the lines. `evince.desktop` in @mgbler's case.

Comment: If you don't know what the name of application is, you can try to find it in `/usr/share/applications`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove anything, you can just change the line in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. It is probably:

```
image/pdf=display-im6.desktop
```

And you want it to be:

```
image/pdf=evince.desktop
```

Where `evince.desktop` is the name of PDF application launcher placed in `/usr/share/applications` that you want to have as default PDF viewer.