# Why do PDF documents open with ImageMagick?

Tags: pdf, default-programs, mime-type, imagemagick, xdg

Query shows `evince` is my default handler.

[image: terminal showing evince as default]

But, double clicking a pdf file opens ImageMagick. A pdf file's *Properties* shows **ImageMagick** as the default handler.

[image: ImageMagick is the default handler]

**Why is this happening ?**

---

<sub>After answering the why, also tell me how to solve it using the terminal. I am very fond of using terminal. I tried `sudo xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf`, nothing changed, even after logging out and back in.</sub>

Answer (score 22):

You might find this is a more clear answer that worked for me in Ubuntu 15.10:

- edit the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
- just remove the lines that associate PDF to imagemagick in the file:

  ```
  image/pdf=display-im6.desktop
  image/pdf=display-im6.q16.desktop;display-im6.desktop;
  ```

The thread where I got this answer that worked for me is here:
[Unable to restore Envince as default pdf viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/570830/unable-to-restore-envince-as-default-pdf-viewer)

Comment: If anyone still strugling check this [feed](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1394118&sid=d21ebb66a331f11bbcbdd813c43578c0#p1394118) it says remove this line `image/pdf=display-im6.desktop` from  `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`

Search for **application/pdf** and amend your viewer there.

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/LGVcyTy5. it also shows evince

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following solution:

```
$ nano ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

and set image/pdf to evince.desktop

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but at one moment ImageMagic took over opening of PDFs. I have totally removed reference to pdf from ~/.config/mimeapps.list 
and pdfs started to open in xreader:

```
grep -v pdf  ~/.config/mimeapps.list > ~/.config/mimeapps.list1 && mv ~/.config/mimeapps.list1  ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Comment: it is suggested not to remove imagemagick as it has dependencies for other apps or functions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what worked fine for is to delete this file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and now I'm even able to change my defaults and it is getting changed unlike before.

Answer (score 0):

"Why do PDF documents open with ImageMagick? After answering the why, also tell me how to solve it using the terminal."

Can't answer either question. However, for folks like myself who just want the fast path to fixing this, when you look at the properties (as shown in your question), simply choose the application you want to be used and "Set as default".

Et voila, it adds an entry to ~/.config/mimeapps.list and you are good to go.

Comment: This is a pretty old question and I'm not sure your solution is actually helpful...

Comment: when you look at the properties and choose "Set as default" image majick  refusess to change from defjault even after I tried to purge image majick with apt